# IntersectObjects - THREE.Line - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a `THREE.Line` object that is used to orchestrate a custom grid.  Now the problem I am having is when using a raycast to `intersectObjects` when the users mouse might goes over this grid, the `intercept` only succeeds if the users mouse goes "directly" over any of the grid lines.

Please see the attached photo:
[image: Custom Grid]

So ultimately what I am am trying to accomplish is, how can the fill in the space between the lines with an "invisible" face or even shape so that when the users mouse goes over this grid, I can trigger an action. Here is currently what I am doing:

```
var response = this.buildGridGeometry(modelStep,modelSize,gridtype);
var geometry = response['geometry'];
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
// #  Setup the material
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2 } );
// #  Draw each individual line
var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material, THREE.LinePieces );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Two suggestions. How about setting the raycasters property linePrecision to a higher value. The documentation defines this property as _The precision factor of the raycaster when intersecting Line objects._. Maybe it can then fill the area between the lines. Second suggestion is to scale and align a PlaneGeometry with the grid (give it the same transformation matrix), then make it `.visible = false;`. When the plane is intersected, you know that line grid is so too.

Comment: Micnil I like the idea of transforming the plane geometry. In your opinion, what's the better option?

Comment: I guess the Plane Geometry would be better if your grid of lines was rectangular, but it looks more "L" shaped. This would mean that you probably would need two planes, making it a bit of a "hacky" solution. Try setting a higher linePrecision first, see if that suits your needs. One consequence of a high linePrecision could be that the grid would intersect a bit outside of the edges. The grid would also intersect as if it had a bit of height. Hope you understand what I mean, otherwise, just try it.

Comment: Micnil could I form a shape to give it the same dimensions as using a plane geometry?  Than set the visibility to hidden.

Comment: Yes that is a good idé! Just use BufferGeometry and create your own shape that looks like you grid. Give it the right initial position, then you can add it as a child object to the grid of lines.

Comment: @micnil what I ended up doing was simply creating a custom shape with an extrude geometry.  If you want to post your suggestion, I will give you the points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create a custom Geometry with the same shape as the grid, then make it's initial position, rotation and scale match with the grid (if it isn't already). After that you can add the custom Geometry as a child to the grid so that it moves correspondingly. Last step is to make the custom Geometry mesh invisible by setting its property `.visible = false;`.

Now you just need to use the raycasters `intersectsObject()` on the custom Geometry mesh instead, and when it does intersect, you know that the grid is intersected aswell.